# How to find the *smallest* number in the list that is close to a given number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers

I wanted to know if there is a way to find the smallest number in the list which is closest to a given number.

Foe e.x.

```
my_list=[1,10,15,20,45,56]
my_no=9
```

Output should be equal to 1
Explanation: since 9 comes between 1 and 10 and I want the smaller number, i.e. 1.

Similarly if my_no=3, output is equal to 1

I am new to python, so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, isn't 9 closer to 10?

Comment: Please share the code from your attempt so far

Comment: @KevinC yes it is, but I want the smaller number. So in this case, 9 comes between 1 and 10. So i want the output to be 1 and not 10

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists

Comment: Does it mean that you just want the largest number from the list that is smaller than your input? What happens in edge cases, i.e. if your input is smaller or larger than all list numbers

Comment: In other words, you want the largest number in the list which is lower than (or equal to?) `my_no`? `max(i for i in my_list if i <= my_no)`…

Comment: Is the list always going to be sorted? What result do you expect when the number is smaller than every number in the list, e.g. ``my_no=0``?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is another elegant way to do this.

```
my_list=[1,10,15,20,45,56]
my_no = 9 
output = max([x for x in my_list if x<=my_no])
print(output) #1
```

Comment: You can omit the `[]` to make it a more efficient *generator expression*.

Comment: If the list is known to be sorted, this is an inefficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` from `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce

i = reduce(lambda l, r: l if l <= my_no <= r else r, my_list)
print(i)

# Output
1
```

Test

```
# my_no = 18
>>> reduce(lambda l, r: l if l <= my_no <= r else r, my_list)
15

# my_no = 59
>>> reduce(lambda l, r: l if l <= my_no <= r else r, my_list)
56
```

Note: this code doesn't work if `my_no < my_list[0]`. You have to check it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to basics and want to approach it using `for loop` and `if statement` then it can be achieved as follows:

```py
my_list=[1,10,15,20,45,56]
given_number = 9

output=my_list[0]
for x in my_list:
  if(x < given_number and x > output):
    output= x

print(output)

# Output
1
```